# Apache Spark Catalyst Parser SQL Exception

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The following scala code (you could run it in a scala worksheet)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser._
import org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf



val sqlParser = new CatalystSqlParser(SQLConf.get)

val query = """select col1 from table1;"""

//import sqlParser.astBuilder
val parsed = sqlParser.parseExpression(query)

//println(astBuilder.toString)
println(s"parsed: ${parsed.prettyJson}")
```

throws what looks like an absurd error -

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input 'from' expecting {<EOF>, '-'}(line 1, pos 12)
== SQL ==
select col1 from table1;
------------^^^
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:266)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parseExpression(ParseDriver.scala:49)
... 37 elided
```

Has anybody seen this before? I saw the error message on SO, but this is a very simple query, and it shouldn't be erroring out this way.

Comment: the parseExpression method parses Expressions (the things that you `SELECT`), not queries.

Comment: Yes,
`sqlParser.parseExpression("(col1, col2)")`
works.

How to parse entire queries?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with calling `CatalystSqlParser` directly, but the `SparkSession.sql` method seems happy with your query. Perhaps using that suits your needs?

The following is successfully parsed:

```
val query = """select col1 from table1;"""
val df = spark.sql(query)
```

(`CatalystSqlParser` doesn't appear to be part of the [documented API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/?search=CatalystSqlParser)).